# FB Android: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-simple-facebook

I'm implementing Facebook Login with android-simple-facebook library.
It works well in Eclipse example, but in my JNI application it crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.
at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:985)                                                   
at com.facebook.Session.openForPublish(Session.java:423)                                         
at com.sromku.simple.fb.SessionManager.openSession(SessionManager.java:237)                      
at com.sromku.simple.fb.SessionManager.reopenSession(SessionManager.java:332)                    
at com.sromku.simple.fb.SessionManager.isLogin(SessionManager.java:123)                          
at com.sromku.simple.fb.SessionManager.login(SessionManager.java:57)                             
at com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook.login(SimpleFacebook.java:171)                            
at com.js.helpers.FBHelper$2.run(FBHelper.java:109)                                              
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)                                           
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)                                           
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)                                                       
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)                                     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                          
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)                                              
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)               
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)                                  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My login implementation is pretty straitforward:

```
    public static void login() {

    final OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFail(String reason) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onLoginListener failed: " + reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OnLoginListener exception: ", throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onThinking() {
            // show progress bar or something to the user while login is happening
            Log.i(TAG, "onLoginListener in progress...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogin() {
            // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in");
            loginCB();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotAcceptingPermissions(Permission.Type type) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLoginListener NotAcceptingPermissions: " + type);
        }
    };

    mSimpleFacebook.login(onLoginListener);
    Log.i(TAG, "FBHelper.login");
}
```

**loginCB** is my native callback function.

The most annoying thing that the problem is floating, the application may login sometimes, but mostly crashes.
I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it was a JNI problem. The following combination made my code working:

- Moving OnLoginListener one level up
- Adding *runOnUiThread*
- Adding *try/catch* block
- Checking *mSimpleFacebook != null* and fixing *IsLoggedIn* function in order not to call for *Login* if already logged in (well, I see that this situation is handled in library, but Facebook really tried to make a duplicate login).

So, my final code is:

```
private static OnLoginListener mOnLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {
         // the same code as in question above
};

public static void login(final Activity activity) {

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mSimpleFacebook == null) 
                mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(activity);
            try {
                mSimpleFacebook.login(mOnLoginListener);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login error: ", ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed: `onActivityResult` in your `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I had this block of code, the problem was in another place.